# What is the potential energy of a bubble due to surface tension?

Tags: energy, work, potential-energy, surface-tension

The following statements are made by Halliday-Resnick:

1. The potential energy of a bubble with surface tension $\gamma$ and radius $r$ is: $U = \gamma \times 2(4\pi r^2)$.
2. The work done in stretching this bubble from radius $r_1$ to $r_2$ is: $\Delta U = \gamma \times 4\pi (r_2^2 - r_1^2)$.

In the 1st expression, they justify the factor of 2 by stating that there is an "inside" and "outside" surface of the bubble that both are stretched and thus contribute to the potential energy. Why does the same argument not apply to the 2nd expression, which is missing this factor of 2?

Comment: That has to be a typo. Did you double check this possibility?

Comment: I considered it might be a typo, but I didn't know enough about this topic to be sure. Does this mean that the factor of 2 is correct and that the second statement was simply forgot this factor?

Comment: Yes, that is what I’m suggesting. I’ll right up a quick answer why very soon. Cheers.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks!

Comment: I suspect that above is a typo, unless there is more information that you have not supplied. If this missing information exists, and it is not a typo, I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surface tension work done here, is the work done in stretching the bubble film, or the change in potential energy, and is therefore $$\Delta W=2\gamma \Delta A$$

This expression needs to include the factor of $2$ since there are *two* surfaces being expanded, so that this work is given by $$\Delta W=8\pi\gamma \left( {r_2}^2-r_1^2\right) $$ This appears to be inconsistent with your point number 2 above, but consistent with point 1. There are *two* surfaces that are in contact with the air and being stretched, so there *must* be a factor of two as in this equation above.